# Why does DiffDay return 0 results

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm totally stuck. I'm trying to query results if a company ID occurs over 2 days.

I mocked up using an object to mock what the database would be and all worked - I'm now using a database

My database is

```
Id         DateTime                          CompanyId
1          2015-02-03 10:30:01:000              5  
2          2015-02-03 10:29:01:000              5
3          2015-02-03 10:27:01:000              5
4          2015-02-03 09:26:01:000              5
5          2015-01-01 10:30:01:000              5
```

Please note, the last entry is the different date!

The below linq is getting the number of days between the max and min values, and if there are differences of more than 1 day, then show the result. `_visitDetail` (below) is the Entity table object.

```
var ids = from o in _visitDetail
          group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
          where (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(grouped.Max(s => s.DateTime), grouped.Min(s => s.DateTime))) > 0
          select grouped;
```

The problem is I always get 0 results where I would expect to get an item. I can't see why or what I've done wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all hidden in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412615%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns:
>   The number of days between dateValue1 and dateValue2.

You have the max first, then the min, so you're getting a negative number of days. Swap them round or do `< 0` in place of `> 0`.

Comment: It isn't actually that clear in the documentation, but I admit, I should have been able to have tested this to work it out myself :(!

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions - sorry for the slightly tongue-in-cheek answer ;) For future reference, profile the database and watch the *actual* sql query being issued to the database, you can then paste this into SSMS and play around with the sql to work out what you've done wrong. In this case adding the resulting `DATEDIFF` part into the select list would have shown you a -ve number.